# C++ FP-tree or Prefix tree

Tags: c++, tree, sequence, prefix, prefix-tree

I have some sequences as these

```
(100) - (102) - (103) - (104,106) - (108)
(101) - (103)
(102) - (106)
```

there is some efficient  implementation an prefix tree or fp-tree or similar in C + +?

Comment: When I was studying a similar algorithm for the implementation of its own, I found [redixtree](http://code.google.com/p/radixtree/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what are you saying... But if you need to build a FP tree here is best page I've found

[FP Tree Algorithm](http://hareenlaks.blogspot.com/2011/06/fp-tree-example-how-to-identify.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you have because the given data doesn't appear to be in any standard notation.

If the prefixes are just a few shared initial decimal digits between integer values, they probably won't make any significant difference to data storage. You could subtract `100` before inserting values into the data structure, store the values as `char`, and add 100 back after retrieval, but it's probably not worth the effort.

Probably you should store the sequence of sequences as a `std::deque< std::vector< int > >` where the `vector` elements are sorted. Unless there is a pattern that I can't see or I'm misinterpreting the problem, optimal performance in finding which sequences contain a given number must be O(N) in the number of sequences times O(lg N) in the sequence length.

Comment: no matter how they are structured my data ..
I care to have a data structure that allows me to store sequences, eg abc, de, f
in particular what I need andis searching efficiently if a sequence x has a prefix equal to some sequence already stored:
example: I have a-b-c-d-and
I look efficientememte if abc is equal to some prefix sequnza others already stored .. to do this using the prefix-tree

Comment: GgSalent: But your example does not contain any common sequence prefixes. You need to slow down and proofread and correct typos, I can't make sense of much of this.